# PHP -> $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR' and Octects

Tags: php, ip

I want to expand the IP range that my `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'` check for. This works:

```
$chk = "10.0.4.";
if( substr($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],0,strlen($chk)) !== $chk)
    $wgGroupPermissions['*']['read'] = false;
```

The following opens up the world to the site:

```
$chk = "10.0.";
if( substr($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],0,strlen($chk)) !== $chk)
    $wgGroupPermissions['*']['read'] = false;
```

I only want my local subnet 10.0.*.* to have read access to the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an extra argument in the second...

```
if (substr($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], 0, strlen($chk)) !== $chk)
```

Comment: I thought I had to add the additional argument because I took away one of the IP address octets.

Comment: The function doesn't care about the contents of the strings, other than saying "yes" or "no".

Comment: why does the first example block everyone not on the 10.0.4.* subnet but the second example opens up the site to the world? Thanks Ignacio.

Comment: If you have another question then you should open another question.

Comment: Sorry. I thought modifying the question might be better. I'll rephrase it and repost it.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the superfluous `,0` from the second line:

```
if( substr($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],0,strlen($chk)) !== $chk)
```